# VueJS - Created global service function with vue provide , get undefined when call the service in vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

i created a vue base project.

What i am trying to do:

- Create a global service function (For call API), in every component able to use `this.$service.service.get()` to call any API that i want, without need to inject.
- Use the app.provide and declare service as a global constant
- Here is my main.js

```js
// main.js

const config = {
    service: createRepository({httpClient})
}
// Vue.prototype.$repository = config.repository;

const app = createApp({
    created() {
    },
    render: () => (
        h(App)
    )
});
app.provide('$service', config.service)
app.mixin(mixin)
app.use(router)
app.mount('#app');
```

```js
// mixin.js
import serviceProvider from "./serviceProvider";

const mixins = [serviceProvider];
const mixin = {
    install: function (Vue, options) {
        mixins.forEach(m => Vue.mixin(m))
    }
}

export default mixin;

//serviceProvider.js
export default {
    beforeCreate() {
        const options = this.$options;
        const service = options.$service || (options.parent ? options.parent.$service : null);
        if (!service) return;

        this.$service = service;
        Object.keys(service).forEach((key, index) => {
            this[`$${key}`] = service[key]
        })
    }
}
```

What is my expected result:

- Expect to see the function being call from the HomePage.vue

```js
// HomePage.vue
async created(){
      await this.$service.authService.get()
}
```

What is my current result:

- authService is undefined

Please advice is that my current setup got any problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[provide](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-provide-inject.html#provide-inject) is useless without `inject`

If you don't want to use `inject`, just use [app.config.globalProperties](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/global-api.html#vue-prototype-replaced-by-config-globalproperties) (replacement of `Vue.prototype` in Vue 2)

`app.config.globalProperties.$service = createRepository({httpClient})`

`this.$service` will now be available in every component in the app...

Comment: Thanks. I try in your way, and it just add the globalProperties would do and dont need to create the ServiceProvider. Could you brief me a bit if without the serviceProvider and what is the different between just using the app.config.globalProperties?

Comment: Frankly it is really hard to understand what you mean. And I do not see any point of whole `serviceProvider`....except maybe spreading `$service` keys into multiple Vue instance properties

Comment: Actually i am trying to control the service which call the API, but still not sure which implementation is the best.

Comment: "best" depends on many things. Using `app.config.globalProperties` is the simplest way. Using provide/inject is probably best if you planning to use [Composition API](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html) because `this` is not available in `setup()` function...